# Memory initialization and addressing in Neural Turing Machines

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

It is not clear to me how the NTM initializes its memory to support content-based addressing with cosine distance. It's clear the initial memory cell values can not be zero but even if you initialize them to some non-zero value (say 1.0), all the cells will look the same and the memory addressing mechanism will produce a uniform distribution over the memory cells. The shift mechanism will just shift this uniform distribution, producing the same uniform distribution and the sharpening might sharpen some value, mainly due to noise.

So I don't see how the memory they described can be used beyond writing the same thing all over the place all the time (if you discount some noise).

Am I missing something and can somebody enlighten me about memory initialization?

Comment: also, random memory initialization seems like a bad idea to me, as well as adding some fixed (trainable) memory addressing bias.

Answer (score 3):

I think I have it figured out. I looked over the interpolation and how it interacts with the shift.

The distribution over the memory cells is part of a memory head's state. The interpolation chooses between the previous distribution and the new distribution generated by the content-based cosine similarity. The shift then can decide to move the head one cell down or one cell up (or stay where it is).

Suppose the memory is empty and the initial addressing distribution is focused around the first memory cell. The content-based mechanism will produce a uniform distribution but the interpolation mechanism can decide to ignore that uniform distribution, taking the initial distribution (focusing on the first cell) and subsequently, the shift can decide to move to the next cell.

So bulk memory population (writing the whole input sequence into memory) would ignore the content-based part.